# How to style a tag for current div with css?

Tags: html, css, tags, styling

My div:

```
 <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <table class="modalWindow" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="feedName" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="renameFeed" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="close">Close it</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Need to style `<a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>` with css for current div.
How to do it?

Comment: `#dialog a { ... }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will style only the a elements with class close (that are a descendant of #dialog), which is what you want: unique control over your close text, not all your link text**

```
#dialog a.close {
   /*insert css here*/
}
#dialog a.close:hover {
   /*insert cool hover css here*/
}
```